# asp.net mvc custom sub routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to set up a custom route like `Admin/Settings/{action}/{id}`

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "AdminSettings",
   url: "Admin/Settings/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { 
       controller = "Settings", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional 
   }
);
```

And I want

`Admin/Settings` - where the controller is Settings and action Index

And

`Admin/Settings/Mail` where the controller is Settings and action Mail

How can I fix this to achieve this routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure this route added to routes collection **before** default route. Otherwise both of your urls are mapped to default route `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. In first case you will have

```
// Admin/Settings
controller = "Admin", action = "Settings"
```

In second case

```
// Admin/Settings/Mail
controller = "Admin", action = "Settings", id = "Mail"
```